# Groovy javax.validation for each List items with List<@NotBlank String>

Tags: validation, groovy, javax.validation

Given this object to validate :

```
 class GroovyTestListItemValidation {

    List<@NotBlank String> inner = []

    GroovyTestListItemValidation(List<String> elements) {
        this.inner.addAll(elements)
    }

}
```

Given this (spock) test:

```
class NotBlankGroovySpec extends Specification{
   

    def "for each collection items with a null, blank or empty"()  {
        given: "An object to validate"
            GroovyTestListItemValidation toBe = new GroovyTestListItemValidation([null," ","","ok"])
        when: "Validation is triggered"
            Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> constraints = validate(toBe)
        then: "3 validation errors are detected"
            constraints.size() == 3
    }

    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> validate(Object input) {
        println("Validating $input")
        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> errs = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().validator.validate(input)
        errs.forEach {
            println("${it.propertyPath} ${it.message}")
        }
        return errs
    }



}
```

The javax.validation constraint : List<@NotBlank String> work fine in java and kotlin (with -Xemit-jvm-type-annotations) but i can't get it working in groovy

Anyone knows a solution please ?

PS: without coding a custom annotation that is already my actual workaround

PS: in kotlin we explicitly ask to keep annotation in bytecode with -Xemit-jvm-type-annotations, i've seen that in the groovy bytecode the annotation is not here, maybe the same trick exists for groovy ?

UPDATE 1:
I've found this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9632 corrected on groovy 4.

This is a groovy 3.0.4 bug corrected on groovy 4, it's a bad thing for me because i can't upgrade to 4...

Comment: Groovy effectively ignores generics by default, try adding `@CompileStatic` to the `GroovyTestListItemValidation` class

Comment: Thnaks @tim_yates, i've already tried that with no success. I've got some more info,  please see update 1 in my question.